# How to extend or implement classes?

Tags: java, class, extends, implements

Picture to show task:
[image]

First I am sorry, for my bad to for expressing my mind.

I have such a task, I don't need that you do it for me.

`Vehicle` is parent class for `Sedan` (Cause Sedan class is String type).

1. How to extend or implement Vehicle class with universal class?
2. I forgot to ask my teacher, but maybe you will know, what means striped pointer to Owner class, and what is that: `has a`?

P.S. If you need code that I have written already, I will show you.

So this is my parent Vehicle class:

```
public class Vehicle {

    private int vehicleNumber;
    protected int fuelTankSize;
    protected int maxSpeed; 
    protected   Owner owner;

    //1
    public Vehicle(int vehicleNumber){
        this.vehicleNumber = vehicleNumber;
    }
    //2
    public Vehicle(int vehicleNumber, int fuelTankSize) {
        this.vehicleNumber = vehicleNumber;
        this.fuelTankSize = fuelTankSize;
    }
    //3
    public Vehicle(int vehicleNumber,  int fuelTankSize, int maxSpeed) {
        this.vehicleNumber = vehicleNumber;
        this.fuelTankSize = fuelTankSize;
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    } 
    //4
    public Vehicle(int vehicleNumber, int fuelTankSize, int maxSpeed, Owner owner) {
        this.vehicleNumber = vehicleNumber;
        this.fuelTankSize = fuelTankSize;
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
            this.owner = owner;
    } 

    //1
    public  int getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }
    public void setMaxSpeed (int maxSpeed){
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }
    //2
    protected int getFuelTankSize(){
        return fuelTankSize;
    }
    protected void setFuelTankSize (int fuelTankSize){
        this.fuelTankSize = fuelTankSize;
    }
    //3
    public Owner getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }
    public void setOwner (Owner owner){
        this.owner = owner;
    }

}
```

child Sedan with:

```
public class Sedan extends Vehicle {

    private String registrationIndex;{      
    }

    public Sedan (int vehicleNumber, int fuelTankSize, int maxSpeed, String registrationIndex, Owner owner) {
        super(vehicleNumber, fuelTankSize, maxSpeed, owner);
        this.setRegistrationIndex (registrationIndex);
    }

    public String getRegistrationIndex (){
        return registrationIndex;
    }
    public void setRegistrationIndex (String registrationIndex) {
        this.registrationIndex = registrationIndex;
    }

}
```

second Universal child without an error:

```
public class Universal extends Vehicle {
    private int trunkSize;

    public Universal (int vehicleNumber, int fuelTankSize, int maxSpeed, int trunkSize, Owner owner) {
        super(vehicleNumber, fuelTankSize, maxSpeed, owner);
        this.setTrunkSize (trunkSize);
    }

    public int getTrunkSize() {
        return trunkSize;
    }
    public void setTrunkSize(int trunkSize) {
        this.trunkSize = trunkSize;
    }

    public void printDescription() {
        super.printDescription();
        System.out.println("Universalo bagažinės tūris: " + getTrunkSize() + "l.");
    }

}
```

and some misterious (to me) Owner class:

```
public class Owner  {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    public Owner (String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Owner (String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

added VechileTest for testing:

```
public class VehicleTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            Vehicle vehicleInf = new Vehicle (1, 45, 260);
            Universal universalInf = new Universal(2, 50, 220, 70);
            Sedan sedanInf = new Sedan (3, 40, 180, "AVA 123");

            vehicleInf.printDescription();
            universalInf.printDescription();
            sedanInf.printDescription();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please refer to the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html or ask a specific question, which I am sure that someone will gladly answer. Cheers!

Comment: Why doesn't your Sedan have a trunk size?

Comment: Don't know :), i am only a person who need to do task, not a man who painted it.

Comment: It's best to show what you already have and what's wrong with it.

Comment: ok, i added some more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, 1st of all I recommend you read a good tutorial / explanation of UML class diagrams, like [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/) here for example.

After you know the basics, it should be easy to translate that into Java code.
I'll give you the code for the `Universal` class and a start for your `Vehicle`. The rest you'll have to do on your own.

The class Universal:

```
public class Universal extends Vehicle {

  private int trunkSize;

  public int getTrunkSize() {
    return this.trunkSize;
  }

  public void setTrunkSize(int trunkSize) {
    this.trunkSize = trunkSize;
  }
}
```

As you can see the first block inside a class box refers to the variables. The `-` and `+` indicates the visibility (private for `-`, public for `+`).

The next block is about the methods, specifying visibility, return type, method name and parameters (type and name).

The arrow between `Universal` and `Vehicle` indicates a inheritance relationship (see in code that `Universal extends Vehicle`).

So all in all the diagram is a construction plan for your classes; at least for the static part, meaning the relationships and state they can have.

The start of class Vehicle:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private int vehicleNumber;
    // the rest here ...
}
```

Edit:
Well, now that I see your code, you seem to have a few misconceptions:

1. The Sedan type is not from type String, it is from type Sedan (which extends Vehicle). Just the new member variable in the Sedan type is of type String, does not matter.
2. To your 1st question: The `Vehicle` class is the base (parent) class of `Sedan`. You do not to do anything with it, inheritance is expressed from the child towards the parent, not the other way around. `Vehicle` should usually be declared abstract (as you cannot create an instance of a generic `Vehicle`), but this is not in the diagram.
3. To your 2nd question: The `has a` relationship is just this. It expressed that one class has another class as it's member (which is redundantely expressed inside the class diagram already), so nothing to do for that.

Additionally your code has a few issues:

1. I do not see any constructors declared in Vehicle class, those 4 can go.
2. Your `Sedan` has a superflous pair of `{}` after declaration of your `registrationIndex` variable.
3. Since your `Vehicle` has no default constructor, you must call this constructor from your `Sedan` class (or remove the constructors from `Vehicle`.
4. Your `Universal` class calls the `Vehicle` constructor with the trunkSize while the `Vehicle` constructor expects the `vehicleNumber` there.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what a was looking for

Comment: @user2956929 Added some further explanation specific to your code.

Comment: Maybe you can write how to call Vehicle from Sedan
P.S. made some changes to Sedan class

Comment: You should handle Sedan's state in Sedan constructor (the registrationIndex) and pass the state of Vehicle to that class by invoking an constructor of Vehicle with super. You have to match one of the existing ones in Vehicle like `public Vehicle(int vehicleNumber)`. So for this you'll have to do something like this `super(4711);` Read up on constructors and inheritance. E.g. here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: silly me and my bad, thank you for showing it!
now i have just need to find out more inf about Owner

Comment: Added some changes. Now i have problems with Owner class in my VehicleTest file: Universal(int int int int0 is undentufied.

Comment: Well, you probably should pass an instance of Owner to the Sedan constructor. Something like `new Owner("Sep", "Meier")`. But really read up on the links I provided above. When you understand these things, it gets easier for you and those things get resolved quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Vehicle` class doesn't have a parameterless constructor, which means that `Universal` and `Sedan` must explicitly call one of them (`super(...);`). You're doing this in `Universal` (albeit incorrectly as you're passing the trunk size instead of the vehicle number expected by `Vehicle`'s constructor) but not in `Sedan`.

As for the second question: The two major relations in OOP are `is a` and `has a`. The difference can be easily explained like this:

- A Sedan is a vehicle
- A vehicle has an owner

`is a` means it inherits some properties of something else, `has a` means that it has a reference to something else.

Comment: Made some changes(you can see it) to Sedan and now it is better, but i get error: "Vehicle(string) is undentified"